# Difference between CA enrollment admin and organization admin fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm following the Blockchain Platform 2.0 Build a network tutorial, and when creating a CA, we specify CA admin credentials in `Enroll ID` and `Secret`

Immediately after, we register an organization admin entity, and I'm a bit confused what the difference is between the CA admin vs. the organization admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Hyperledger Fabric, the Membership Service Provider (CA) and organizations are separate entities. The MSP/CA is reponsible only for maintaining identities. The organization admin has different privileges - such as maintaining the organization's endorsing/ordering/validation peers.

For more, see: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html